# Roblox not checking when bool value is updated?

Tags: boolean, roblox

So I've been trying to make a script on Roblox where tubes turn black when a Boolean is changed to false but it doesn't detect when it becomes false.

```
local Coolant = workspace.Temperature.CoolantActive
local CoolTube = workspace.TheCore.Coolant.Cool1

while true do
    if Coolant.Value == true then
        CoolTube.Material = ("Neon")
        CoolTube.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Toothpaste")
    elseif Coolant.Value == false then
        CoolTube.Material = ("Metal")
        CoolTube.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really black")
    end
    wait(1)
end
```

I have no idea why this is happening, help?!

Comment: When you say it's not detecting it, is it not changing the color of the parts or is it airways going down the same code path? Are there any errors in the Output window?

Comment: No errors in output. It just doesn't change the colours and materials @Kylaaa

Comment: If you add print statements anywhere in the script, do those appear? Is this a Script? The Script isn't Disabled right?

Comment: I've tried adding print statements and it prints when it's enabled but when i change the value to disabled it keeps printing the enabled one

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a loop run forever, try using the [Changed signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/BoolValue/Changed) to detect when the Value changes.

```
local Coolant = workspace.Temperature.CoolantActive
local CoolTube = workspace.TheCore.Coolant.Cool1

Coolant.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
    if newValue == true then
        CoolTube.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        CoolTube.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Toothpaste")
    else
        CoolTube.Material = Enum.Material.Metal
        CoolTube.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really black")
    end
end)
```

Comment: No idea what's happening. No matter if I try it on a normal brick i've just placed or the object the script was made for. Nothing is happening.